# Problem with launching scrapy spider from sh script

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, sh

When I try to run my sh script with a spider, it displays only one warning and does not parse, but when I run the spider on my own, the parsing goes fine

my sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
# shellcheck disable=SC2164
cd /var/www/scrapy_parser/avito/avito/spiders
scrapy crawl avito -L WARNING
cd /var/www/scrapy_parser/info/info/spiders
scrapy crawl info_v1 -L WARNING.
```

sh output:

```
WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py:210: 
ScrapyDeprecationWarning: The `FEED_URI` and `FEED_FORMAT` settings have been deprecated in 
favor of the `FEEDS` setting. Please see the `FEEDS` setting docs for more details
exporter = cls(crawler)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: When you run the spider on your own, don’t you also get the same warning? Otherwise, you would be using different Scrapy versions, or the spiders may be using different settings.

Comment: @Gallaecio To avoid problems with the versions I decided to put scrapy globally. Yes, I understand that it’s better not to do this, but for me it was the simplest solution to this problem because of the close deadline.And as you can see, I have two projects in one folder, therefore, the settings for each are different, which is why I sincerely do not understand why the script cannot run them through

Comment: Compare the logs when you run a spider manually and when you run it through the script. Look for any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I solved this problem by logging, in the end it turned out that the site that I parse blocked me as a bot and the sh script did not read the pre-installed proxies in the system, I solved everything by adding the proxy setting directly to the sh script before starting the spider